# Why does my machineKey change every time I push a new version of my Azure web role?

Tags: asp.net, security, azure

I have a question - why does the machine key yielded by this function return a different value every time I restart my Azure web roles in the Azure Compute emulator? I have a hard-coded, generated machine key in my Web.config for this role - shouldn't that be enough?

```
 var cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
 var machineKey = (MachineKeySection)cfg.GetSection("system.web/machineKey");
```

What's the correct way of handling this in Azure web roles?

I'm using my machine keys for hashing user data, so it's important that I don't have dynamic machine keys obviously :p

Comment: Does this have anything to do with why my machine key is being regenerated? http://blogs.itmentors.com/bill/2009/11/04/configuration-files-and-windows-azure/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue, discussed in detail in [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/e2279dbe-d3e4-44a8-8f07-9e93a8e57486). The workaround, also mentioned in the thread, is published [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg494983.aspx).