# Anti-Forgery Token cannot be decrypted in asp MVC website hosted in Azure Web Site (After trying various solution)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I know there are some question about it, but it does not seem to work for my case. I am a bit surprised that the question is not that popular, considering many websites around are built in  asp MVC, and I guess all of those have something to do with it.

The problem is basic, my MVC website that is hosted in azure website gives this error when I try to change password for userIdentity (Manage Action in Account controller).

***The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.***

I used this machinekey:

```
<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" validationKey='AC0DA63E787522E3BA5D47D8FA0A46EB68BB89A35C6353D5E8D3D5CA416D0DA607E56C6D0861ED3B7194C3ED74C0CE79FE4CE2909F34A6CFBDE134C1A094CA40' decryptionKey='A68360896EF374401123C6C222A7AAD8D430DB4DE34938E1' validation='SHA1'/>
```

But still no use. In addition, I extracted this machinekey from a third party. I know it is not safe but the microsoft way is too complicated: using powershell to generate it? complicated. Then using IIS? My IIS8 is not showing machinekey module. What on earth is going on with all of these stuff.

Okay, maybe the error is caused by a multiple @html.antiforgerytoken. Well, I had indeed two antiforgerytoken, but when I remove one of them, the error persisted.

I am so frustated with this problem. I hope someone will be kind enough to help. I believe those MVC users have been in this situation when developing MVC web site. In my case, I am just a newbie and this is my first MVC web site that is deployed.

One more note: even running in debug mode in localhost, it gives the same error.

thanks for you help

**UPDATE**

controller:

```
// POST: /Account/Manage
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
    {
        bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        if (hasPassword)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // User does not have a password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
            ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
            if (state != null)
            {
                state.Errors.Clear();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@using percobaan2.Models;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Manage Account";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutManage.cshtml";
}

<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4 offset4 blog-details">

    <p class="text-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <article class="center">

            @if (ViewBag.HasLocalPassword)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Partial("_SetPasswordPartial")
            }

        </article>
    }
</div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- META DATA -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

<meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.WebsiteTitle">

<title>@ViewBag.Title - @ViewBag.WebsiteTitle</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/ico/favicon.png">

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<!-- GOOGLE WEB FONTS -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,700,600,300,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="fixed-top fixed-visable" id="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12 center">
                <!-- MOBILE MENU BUTTON -->
                <div class="mobile-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- END MOBILE MENU BUTTON -->
                <!-- MAIN MENU -->
                <ul id="main-menu" class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { Area = "Admin", id = 1 })">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Slide", new { Area = "Admin" })">Tagline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Division", new { Area = "Admin" })">Division</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contact", new { Area = "Admin" })">Yahoo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Email", new { Area = "Admin" })">Email</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { Area = "Admin" })">Product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Category", new { Area = "Admin" })">Category</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Producer", new { Area = "Admin" })">Producer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Unit", new { Area = "Admin" })">Unit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Activity", new { Area = "Admin" })">Activity</a></li>
                    @*@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")*@
                </ul>
                <!-- END MAIN MENU -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- END NAVIGATION -->
<!-- PAGE | BLOG -->
<div class="pages page-blog-list" id="page-blog-list">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Header -->
        <header id="headerUpper" class="headerAdmin">
            <h4 class="line-divider">Admin</h4>
            <h1>Change Password</h1>
        </header>
        <!-- End Header -->

            @RenderBody()

    </div>
</div>
<!-- END PAGE | BLOG -->

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/plugins")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/blog")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Login Partial:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", new { Area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Account", "Manage", "Account", new { Area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">
            Log off
        </a>
    </li>

    @*<li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Account", "Manage", "Account", new { Area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage", @class = "phoneNumber" })
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" class="phoneNumber logOffPadding">
                Log off
            </a>
        </li>*@

}
}
else
{
@*@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", new { Area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", @class = "phoneNumber" })*@

<li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", new { Area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class = "phoneNumber logInPadding" })
</li>
}
```

**.NET Vesion: 4.5**

Comment: what does your controller look like? what about the view? I'm using anti-forgery token on Azure Web-site with no issues. What .Net version are you using?

Comment: Okay i will update sir

Comment: @trailmax I updated the code to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882245/why-does-my-machinekey-change-every-time-i-push-a-new-version-of-my-azure-web-ro

Comment: @ta.speot.is the forum is no longer exist for the workaround. can you rephrase it here sir?

Comment: The first link in the answer is http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e2279dbe-d3e4-44a8-8f07-9e93a8e57486/azure-sdk-13-and-machine-key?forum=windowsazuredevelopment which says *he basic idea is to overwrite the machineKey element during your role startup.*